# Using Travis CI with Android

Tags: android, github, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

I've been looking at the [Travis CI docs for Android](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/), so I can learn how to start using Travis for my Android library. However, I don't understand a lot of what the documentation says...

So far, what I understand is:

```
language: android  # this means the project will be built in an Android environment

android:
  components:
    - tools               # will be built with latest version of Android SDK tools
    - platform-tools      # ''
    - build-tools-23.0.1  # build tools version of my project
    - android-23          # Android SDK version of my project
```

The Travis CI docs also show additional components that can be used:

```
# Additional components
- extra-google-google_play_services
- extra-google-m2repository
- extra-android-m2repository
- addon-google_apis-google-19
```

and it gives a more complete list [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#Pre-installed-components).

**But what do these 'additional components' do/mean?** I'm guessing that perhaps the `extra-android-support` component means the project will be built with the Android Support library, but what about the others?

I've had a look at [Travis tests for Gradle](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#Default-Test-Command-for-Gradle), but I've seen other projects use `script: ./gradlew check`, `script: ./gradlew clean build check`, `script: "./gradlew build"`, and some with no `script` at all. **What does all of this mean?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your `.travis.yml` file, you are configuring a machine to build and to run your code. In this file you have to specify all components that you need.

The doc shows all the SDK components that are already available (preinstalled). You don't need to specify them in your .travis.yml file, unless you want to force re-installation of this component.

Instead you have to specify the components that aren't preinstalled.
For example there is only the `build-tools 21.1.1` on the list. It was a decision of the team because there are more frequent version updates for this component.

> what do these 'additional components' do/mean?

```
- extra-google-google_play_services
- extra-google-m2repository
- extra-android-m2repository
```

These are the support library repositories (the same that you have to update with your SDK Manager) from which gradle downloads the support libraries added in the dependencies block of your `build.gradle` file.

To get a list of available exact component names and descriptions run the command `android list sdk --no-ui --all --extended`.
You will get somenthing like:

```
# Check Android SDK tools: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html
# Check Android SDK Platform-tools: http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html
tools
platform-tools

# Check BuildTools: http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html
build-tools-23.0.1

# The API to be used to compile
# Check APIs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

android-23
android-22
android-21
android-20
android-19
android-18
android-17
android-16
....

# The system images if you need to run emulator during your tests

sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
sys-img-x86-android-23
....

# Google repository from which download the dependencies

# Check extras: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html#GetSupportLib
extra-android-m2repository
extra-android-support

# Check more extras: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html#GetGoogle
extra-google-m2repository
extra-google-google_play_services

extra-google-admob_ads_sdk
extra-google-analytics_sdk_v2
extra-google-gcm
extra-google-google_play_services_froyo
.....

# Source file
source-23
source-22
source-21

...
```

With your `.travis.yml` you have to tell travis how to check if your **BUILD is SUCCESSFUL**. With the `script` block you specify which commands to use to check the build.
If your project has a `build.gradle` file in the repository root, Gradle will be used to build it. It can be enough for you, it depends by your project.

The default command used with gradle is:

```
./gradlew build connectedCheck
```

but you can override it specyfing the script block.

More info [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/).

If you would like to see an output in travis-ci you can check [this](https://travis-ci.org/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators).

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! Just a few questions: 1) you mentioned the `android list sdk --no-ui --all --extended` to get a list of all components - where do I run this command (Windows cmd, terminal in Android Studio, or something else?); 2) what's the difference between `extra-google-m2repository` and `extra-android-m2repository`?. 3) What are the source files (`source-23`, `source-22`, etc.)?. Thanks again for a very well explained answer!

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh Updated the answer with some info. 1)You can use the `android list sdk` command in the script in the `before_install:` block.  2) check the answer. The first is the google repository for google play service library , the second for the support libraries (appcompat, v4). You can check it also in you sdk folder `androidSdk/extras`. 3) The source file of the android classes as in the sdk manager.

Comment: After adding the script in the `before_install:` block, how would I see the results? (I hope this isn't a silly question...)

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh in your travis machine, in the output.